# css responsive design: how to improve my page ?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have experience in web development but zero experience in mobile development. I have therefore purchased a website template (html5 +css3) and I then used it as a starting point for a PHP website.

Some of the pages are not working very well on mobile though. When I test [this page](http://www.samuel-berthelot.fr/prestations), the text is not sizing to the mobile screen. Even worse, when I go into Reader mode on iOS, there's just this big image of silver rings showing, instead of the actual text.

How can this be fixed ?

The code responsible for showing a block of text is the following:

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="content_block row">
                <div class="fl-container span9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="posts-block span12">
                            <div class="contentarea">

                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span12 module_cont module_text_area module_medium_padding">
                                        <h3 class="headInModule"></h3>

                                        <p>Les prestations commencent à partir de 250 euros.</p>

                                        <p>Lors de ma prestation, je suis à votre entière disposition pendant un
                                            nombre d’heures qui varie en fonction de la formule choisie. </p>

                                        <p>Je m’engage à délivrer les photos dans un délai de 4 semaines suivant le
                                            mariage.</p>

                                        <p>Les frais de déplacement sont inclus dans la région Alsace-Lorraine,
                                            Luxembourg et Province Luxembourg en Belgique. Pour toute autre région,
                                            veuillez me contacter.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- .row-fluid -->

                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span12 module_cont module_text_area module_medium_padding">
                                        <img src="/img/bronze.jpg" alt="formule bronze"
                                             style="float:left"/>

                                        <div style="float:right">
                                            <h3 class="headInModule">Formule Bronze</h3>
                                            <a id="anchor1"></a>

                                            <ul class="list_type1">
                                                <li>6H de prestation le jour du mariage * (plage horaire à préciser
                                                    avec les mariés)
                                                </li>
                                                <li>Rencontre des futurs mariés avant le mariage et signature du
                                                    contrat de prestation
                                                </li>
                                                <li>La prestation comprend un photo reportage permettant de couvrir
                                                    les thèmes suivants:
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>préparatifs (habillage, maquillage, coiffeur)</li>
                                                        <li>cérémonie</li>
                                                        <li>photos de couple ou/et de groupe</li>
                                                        <li>vin d’honneur</li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>Travail de post-production et de retouches</li>
                                                <li>1 DVD contenant les photos retravaillées en haute résolution
                                                    (min. 150 photos)
                                                </li>
                                                <li>Galerie photo internet sécurisée et disponible pendant 1 an
                                                    minimum.
                                                </li>
                                                <li>Cession intégrale des droits de reproduction dans un cadre privé
                                                    uniquement.
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <i>prix sur demande</i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- .row-fluid -->
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Comment: that looks great, but how is this going to help ? I don't use tables at all in my layout and I don't want to display tabular data, but just plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes `.span9` and `.span12` has a width of 700px and 940px which is stretching your content. If you set these to 100% in your media queries it should work.

e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px){
     .span9, .span12 {width:100%;}
}
```